# Can i exclude files dynamically from ts compiler?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I'm setting up a node/typescript server to build a real time application. I have my server and my client on the same folder.

What i want to do is to exclude "src/client" from the typescript compiler when i run the "server:dev" script end exclude "src/server" when i run "client:dev".

I already tried to find a way to exclude files from command line, but i didn't find solutions for that.

that's how my tsconfig.json look like

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",                          
    "module": "commonjs",                     
    "lib": ["dom","es2017"],                  
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",                         
    "strict": true,                           
    "noImplicitAny": true,                     
    "moduleResolution": "node",                  
    "esModuleInterop": true,                     
    "resolveJsonModule": true                 
  },
  "exclude": [
      "src/client"
  ]
}
```

but i need to include "src/client" and exclude "src/server" when i run the client.

Comment: You can have two tsconfig files (they can extend the common one)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`tsconfig.json` support `extends` field, in your case, you should put the common config in a base `tsconfig.json`, then create tsconfig with `extends` for client and server respectively.

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...               
  }
}

// tsconfig.client.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...               
  },
  "exclude": ["src/server"]
}

// tsconfig.server.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...               
  },
  "exclude": ["src/client"]
}
```

For npm scripts:

```
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "server:dev": "tsc --build tsconfig.server.json",
    "client:dev": "tsc --build tsconfig.client.json",
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work now. The tsc doesn't report error.  But when I add --verbose.  It tells me the tsconfig.server.json is out of date because output filed doesn't exist.  Is it supposed to overwrite the output file?

Comment: `extends` is still a valid field, so it should work. could you show an example with codesandbox/stackblitz?

Comment: False alarm.  I have figured it out.  It caused by a noEmit: false inherited from the tsconfig.json. It's add for the vite.  But this flag block output when building the server without vite.

Answer (score 0):

The general approach to change the compiler options dynamically:

since `fs` module can be used in node.js, you could add this util function to your node.j sproject:

```
const fs = require("fs")
const prettier = require("prettier")

function changeTs(){
    // this guarantees that I am on server
    if(typeof window === "undefined"){
      // process.cwd returns base folder, current working directory
      // whatever path is
      const tsPath = path.join(process.cwd(), "tsconfig.json")
      const tsConfig = require(tsPath)
      tsConfig.compilerOptions.exclude = ["src/client"]
       fs.writeFileSync(
           tsPath,
           prettier.format(
           JSON.stringify(tsConfig), { parser: "json" }
             )
           )
    
      }  
  }
```

call the above function, top-level when node.js app loads, so it tsconfig.json will be updated. default setting should be `"exclude": ["src/server"]`. When you are on server, it will be changed to  `"exclude": ["src/client"]`

With this approach, you can even pass an argument to the function, so you can change the ts compiler options based on a specific setting that your app needs.